# Reading MultiDiGraph as dict-of-dicts ignores multigraph_input

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

In NetworkX 2.5 I can't seem to read in a multigraph using a dict-of-dicts. Here's an example trying to round-trip some data:

```
G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=5)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=4)  # Create 2 edges

dict_of_dicts = nx.to_dict_of_dicts(G)
G2 = nx.MultiDiGraph(dict_of_dicts, multigraph_input=True)

print("Original", G.edges(data=True))
print("Round tripped", G2.edges(data=True))
print(G2.number_of_edges(), "edge(s) in round tripped graph")
```

Giving only a single edge in the round-tripped graph G2:

```
Original [(2, 3, {'weight': 5}), (2, 3, {'weight': 4})]
Round tripped [(2, 3, {0: {'weight': 5}, 1: {'weight': 4}})]
1 edge(s) in round tripped graph
```

So what's the format for reading in a MultiDiGraph as a dict-of-dicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me using the [`nx.from_dict_of_dicts`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_dict_of_dicts.html) with both `create_using` and `multigraph_input` parameters used worked:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=5)
G.add_edge(2, 3, weight=4)  # Create 2 edges

dict_of_dicts = nx.to_dict_of_dicts(G)
G2 = nx.from_dict_of_dicts(dict_of_dicts, create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph(), multigraph_input=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've just found that too. Strange that it doesn't work when directly instantiating `nx.MultiDiGraph`. Is this a bug, do you think?

Comment: If you pass the data to the create of `MultiDiGraph` it is forwarded to `DiGraph` init, which may handles parts different (resulting in your observed difference). You could try to open an issue at: https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues and check their. I'm not sure if all possibilities for MultiGraph are that much tested.

Comment: I've just done that at https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/4720. Thanks.